# Can't import sql file through command line

Tags: mysql, import

I am trying to import an sql file through the commmand line in Windows 7 with no luck. I know there are other questions on here that deal with this but NOTHING in any of the answers has helped me.

The file is too large for a PHPMyAdmin import. It is a 500mb post code file.

I have tried various different methods to connect and/or import:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -uroot –padmin postcodetest < C:\fullukpostcodes.sql

C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql –uroot –padmin postcodetest < C:\fullukpostcodes.sql

mysql> use postcodetest;
mysql> source C:\fullukpostcodes.sql;
```

Nothing is working. All that is happening is that I am getting a dump of some file (maybe PHP.ini).

[image]

Please help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you get is _not_ a dump of "some file", but an explanation of how to use the command! Read it!

Comment: Not sure about MS-Windows (as most others here I don't use it), but usually there must be a space between an option identifier and its argument like this: `mysql –u root –p admin .....` This _might_ be different on MS-Windows compared to all other systems, but give it a try.

Comment: @arkascha It is not necessary to have a space between the options you have mentioned.

Comment: I don't use the mysql command line, but I'm pretty sure there is no error message that says "*Nothing is working*". You should show us what exactly happens when you run the statements.

Comment: Thanks for the sarcasm. What do you think is the image I posted? That is what I am getting.

Comment: Yep, and first there is no message like "no working" and second it is the answer to your question, but you did not read or understand it.

Comment: Can you take the screenshot again, but this time scroll the window up a little so that we can see the command?

Answer (score 1):

Try this command in command line

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Note : please provide the actual path of your sql file